# Group by with MIN value in same query while presnting all other columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a view called `a` with this data:

```
 ID    tDate        name     task   val
23   2015-06-14
23   2015-06-25
126  2015-06-18
126  2015-06-22
126  2015-06-24
```

`ID` is integer and `tDate` is timestamp.

Basically I want to get for each `ID` the min value of `tDate` and present this row.
meaning:

```
ID   tDate       name     task   val
23   2015-06-14
126  2015-06-18
```

I wrote this query:

```
select ID, min(tDate)
from a
group by ID
order by ID
```

This is working **BUT** it doesn't allow me to present all other columns of `a`

for example if I do:

```
select ID, min(tDate), name
from a
group by ID
order by ID
```

it says that name must be under group by. So I wrote this query:

```
select ID, MIN(tDate), name, task, val , ....
from a
group by ID, name, task, val , ....
order by ID
```

And this one **doesn't work**. it gives false results.

How do I solve it?

Comment: you should not do group by on all those columns, which is slow and may give you wrong result

Comment: @Tim3880 I know that... this is exactly what I got. My question is how to fix it.

Comment: This is one of the things I find annoying about SQL. If you want an aggregate grouped by a single (or multiple) column, you can only include those column(s) in the select list. You have to join a subquery, selecting the aggregate and ID fields, on the grouped columns (and on the aggregate if it is something like max, not like count).

Comment: Do you see a case were @Gordon Linoff answer will give false results? he suggested to do it without sub queries.

Comment: That should work, but it is specific to PostgreSQL. I generally use SQL Server, which does not support `select distinct on`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres has the very convenient `distinct on` for this type of problem:

```
select distinct on (id) a.*
from a
order by id, tdate;
```

This will return one row for each `id`.  The row is the first one determined by the ordering defined in the `order by` clause.

Comment: But how will it give me the MIN(tDate)?

Comment: @John . . . It gives you the smallest value of `tDate` because of the `order by` clause.

Comment: it says  `ERROR: syntax error at or near ","` on the Select statement.

Comment: Try: `select distinct on (id) a.*`

Comment: I think the `on` word is whats making it not to compile

Comment: Are you using PostgreSQL or another version? This will only work for Postgre.

Comment: What about this:
`select distinct on (id) a.*
from a as a
order by id, tdate;`

Comment: I don't have access to PostgreSQL at the moment, so I'm just looking for common issues. If this doesn't work, a subquery definitely will.

Comment: @Wolves . . . The comma was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Do a join from the one table to a sub-query table on just the ID / Min Date

```
select
      YT.ID,
      YT.tDate as OriginalDate,
      PQ.MinDate,
      YT.name,
      YT.task,
      YT.val
   from
      YourTable YT
         JOIN ( select ID, min( tdate ) as MinDate
                   from YourTable
                   group by ID ) as PQ
         on YT.ID = PQ.ID
        AND YT.tDate = PQ.MinDate
   order by
      ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
select a.id, a.tdate , .... from a
join (select id, min(tdate) min_date   
from a
group by ID
) b
on a.id=b.id and a.tdate = b.min_date
order by a.id
```